Electron: How to detect if window is maximized to change maximize icon
I've made a custom titlebar in electron with the icons taken straight from the Windows UI kit.

How can I detect whenever the window is maximized, whether it's by double clicking the titlebar or dragging it to the top of the screen, in another script rather than the main one. I need to change the maximize icon to a "restore" icon when maximized.
I'm aware of this method:
mainWindow.on('maximize', () => {
    // do something
})

But I can only modify the HTML in the frontend JS file, not the main one.

If you created a custom titlebar, you must have used IPC for the buttons to update the window. In order to change the HTML from main, you have to also use it here:
Main
mainWindow.on("maximize", () => {
  mainWindow.webContents.send("maximize");
});

(You may want to listen to the unmaximize event too.)
Preload
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require("electron");

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electronAPI', {
  onMaximize: (callback) => (
    ipcRenderer.on("maximize", () => callback())
  )
});

Renderer
window.electronAPI.onMaximize(() => {
  // Do something with your HTML
});


As a side note, if you want your app to keep the maximized state on lunch, you will need to store the state before close (with a tool such as electron-store for example), and make your renderer check the state of the window when it's loaded:
Main
const { app, ipcMain } = require("electron");

// Note that starting with version 9,
// `electron-store` is ESM and `require` will not work.
const Store = require("electron-store");

const store = new Store({
  schema: {
    isMaximized: { type: "boolean" }
  }
});

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  ipcMain.handle("isMaximized", () => mainWindow.isMaximized());
})

mainWindow.once("ready-to-show", () => {
  if (store.get("isMaximized")) mainWindow.maximize();
});

mainWindow.on("close", (event) => {
  store.set("isMaximized", mainWindow.isMaximized());
});

Preload
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require("electron");

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electronAPI', {
  isMaximized: () => ipcRenderer.invoke("isMaximized")
});

Renderer
await window.electronAPI.isMaximized((isMax) => {
  // Do something with your HTML
});


After using your code, I get a ton of errors, seemingly about the preload script.
Here's a screenshot https://imgur.com/a/nJr374s

@ArtinGoodarzi It's because you need to import ipcRenderer and contextBridge in order to use them. I've updated my examples to include the imports.

Actually, I still get these errors. My preload script is unable to load for some reason.

@ArtinGoodarzi Make sure you use the correct path to your preload and also that you have not disabled security feature such as contextIsolation. Tbh, I can't see how you have been able to make you buttons work at all if you have not used the preload yet. The only way would be to disable security and use Electron directly in your renderer (which you should not do unless you're very sure of what you're doing).

Turning on contextIsolation worked. To add to what you said, I actually never had to use the preload script at all to make the window controls work, just IPC, why should I? Is that what you're supposed to do?

@ArtinGoodarzi I'm glad you found the solution! If you want to follow all security recommendations, you should turn off nodeIntegration and turn on contextIsolation, sandbox and webSecurity (these is their default state). And then you should only (and will only be able to) use IPC via the preload.

Turning off nodeIntegration now makes my entire javascript stop working  . Other than that i'm good.

@ArtinGoodarzi That's because you coded with security off, so when you turn it on, everything break. Basically, you should not use electron and Node.js directly in your renderer without using the preload. Would you consider accepting my answer if it solved your issue?
